# using purrr to loop query a server and populate a column

Tags: r, purrr

I am trying to use `purrr` to populate a new column in a data frame.

The frame contains a list of endpoint from a server I then have a function that uses `httr` to get the endpoint status but I can't seem to get it to work?

example is:

```
require(tibble)
require(purrr)
require(httr)
require(RCurl)
require(dplyr)

example = tibble(
  processor = c('A', 'B', 'C'),
  code = c('s3zsf3', 'a2ssf3', 'g6zsf6')
  )

GetStatusOfProcessing <- function(identifier, tserver) {
      url = paste0( tserver,identifier )
      data = content(GET(url))
      data$runStatus # this is a string
}

server = 'http://localhost:8080/'

Output <- example %>%
  map(GetStatusOfProcessing(., server)) 

Expected_Output_example = tibble(
      processor = c('A', 'B', 'C'),
      code = c('s3zsf3', 'a2ssf3', 'g6zsf6'),
      Status = c('RUNNING', 'RUNNING', 'RUNNING')
    )
```

How can I use `map` to properly feed in the row by row id or is that the wrong function to use?

Comment: What goes where? This example isn't really reproducible. Maybe `example %>% mutate(status = map_chr(code, GetStatusOfProcessing, tserver = server))`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
Output <- example %>% 
            mutate(Status = map_chr2(processor, code, GetStatusOfProcessing))
```